# Do chainlink data-feeds have specific guarantees about returning new data within N-Blocks?

Tags: chainlink

As an application developer, how can i guarantee that the data that I am reading is not stale? I am not able to find the answer to this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your question as asking about data "freshness".
"Each Chainlink Price Feed runs on a specific blockchain network and regularly updates with fresh data based on predefined parameters. " [ref](https://blog.chain.link/chainlink-price-feeds-secure-defi/)

Also take a look at [timestamps on retrieved answers](https://docs.chain.link/docs/using-chainlink-reference-contracts/#check-the-timestamp-of-the-latest-answer)

Example ETH/USD feed parameters - note "Last Update" parameters  ([link](https://data.chain.link/ethereum/mainnet/crypto-usd/eth-usd))